# change of select list to radio buttons

Tags: commerce

when i try to change the attribute field settings under my custom field in my product to radio buttons, it does not display anything in the product display content type anymore, but when i change it back to select list, its okay..

i want to use radio buttons because i want to style it..

[image]

the one circled in red is in select list, while the one ricled in blue is in radio button.[image]
here's the attribute field, when i change it to radio buttons, it does not display anything in the prodcut display page. really blank..

**EDIT:**
so i found the problem, the node cant handle too many radio button.. i tried creating a custom line item, then added to fields, first field is users>list(integer)>checkbox/radio button, it is fine, but when i added the 2nd field storage_size>list(text)>checkbox/radio button, it doenst show anything again,

my conclusion, too many radio buttons in that node will make it display nothing.. any workaround regarding this problem? Thank you!!

Comment: why would't you be able to style the selectbox?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't something else going on here? I've never seen an issue in developing / testing core Drupal Commerce with this not appearing as expected.

Comment: @Frogger the markup is different... i want to create like a slider css using the radio button

Comment: is there a maximum number of referenced product that can be used in one content type? because there are times i can only add 45 products to display, when i add another 1, it displays nothing. i used term reference in some of my products field

Comment: ive got 3 custom field in my custom product type, field A has 9 types, field b has 11 types and field C has 5 types, so there will be like 9x11x5 495 products in my node to be selected.. any hint to work with this?